# How can I create an index in RavenDb that returns docs filtered by more than one "subvalue"

Tags: ravendb

I have a document containing a list of nodes and I need to return documents that are filtered by more than one node.

E.g.
I have 2 docs

```
doc1 = {nodes: [{name:"node1", state:"1"}, {name:"node2", state:"2"]}
doc2 = {nodes: [{name:"node1", state:"1"}, {name:"node2", state:"1"]}
```

I would like to be able to create an index that will select a doc based on the state of both the nodes:

that is I would like to do something of this sort:

```
from doc in docs
from node in doc.nodes
where (node.name == "node1" && node.state == "1")
&& (node.name == "node2" && node.state != "2")
select new { doc }
```

This does not work and I have not found any good examples doing similar stuff.

Sorry about being unclear:

```
from doc in docs.CorporateInsuranceOffer
from node in doc.offerDetails.nodes 
where (node.name == "radgjof" && node.state == "state4" )  
&& (node.name == "verdlagning" && node.state != "state4" )  
select new {created = doc.offerInfo.created, offerId = doc.offerInfo.offerId, changed = doc.offerInfo.changed, kennitala = doc.offerInfo.kennitala, owner = doc.offerInfo.owner }
```

This is the actual query, it does not cause errors, it just returns no data (but should return 2 documents -- verified by using 1 of the wheres at a time and comparing the results).

My problem seems to be that I can not set conditions on 2 different nodes in the same document.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you are using and the error message you get? You certainly can use a Where(..) clause within your index, for instance a common scenario is where (node.name != null)....

Comment: But also, as Danial says, you probably don't want to just do "select new { doc }", you need to just specify the fields that you will use in the query.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an index in RavenDB, you actually define a map-function that will map/extract some information out of your documents and pass them along to Lucene for later querying. It is important to understand that the "select" in your linq index definition should *select* the criteria on which you want to query afterwards. This means you need to select the properties on which you want to query upon, not the whole document itself.

Either define an index that looks like this

```
from doc in docs
from node in doc.nodes
select new { node.name, node.state }
```

or better, just query for whatever you need (without defining an index upfront) and let RavenDB find out what index you'll need.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I am aware of that however I would like to have the resulting set smaller than all the documents. As for doing an ad-hoc query I need the index to do the filtering if at all possible because of the access pattern we are using.

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems I have misunderstood your question. Can you post some code or the actual error as Matt suggests?

Answer (score 0):

Well, one problem is that your query is never going to return results, because a node name can never test true for two separate values on the same property.

i.e.:

```
(node.name == "node1" && node.state == "1") && (node.name == "node2" && node.state != "2")
```

Here "node" is the same entity in all cases. This query will always return an empty set.

Assuming your enumerable nodes property always has two elements you might try this. It is not pretty but  should work:

```
from doc in docs
where (doc.nodes.ElementAt(0).name == "radgjof" && doc.nodes.ElementAt(0).state == "state4")
&& (doc.nodes.ElementAt(1).name == "verdlagning" && doc.nodes.ElementAt(1).state == "state4")
select new
{
    doc
};
```